Git deletes added files after merge with moved files
We have such structure of SQL scripts per release and pending ones:
 deployment/
   4.9.0/
   5.0.0/
 pending/


Once a decision is made to prepare a new release, we do merges from various feature branches into the develop one and finally, when everything is tested, prepared, etc. all SQL scripts from the pending folder are moved (using "git mv") one by one into a folder with the release number, e.g. 5.0.1.
When the release is out, we merge develop branch into active feature branches. So far, everything is good.
The problem happens (and I can't understand it and can't understand how to avoid that), when while a release is being prepared, someone is actively working in a feature branch and wants to push the changes. You realize that you should first pull and all SQL scripts that were previously in the pending folder are moved by git into 5.0.1 folder (that's fine, as those files are the part of just made release and they are not "pending" anymore).
But this "move" deletes also all files from the pending folder that you've added working on your local changes. Why? And thanks to possible conflicts as the result of pull - only in this case you can notice that the files that you've added into pending are deleted and can revert that "delete". But if a pull didn't produce any conflicts, your files are just silently deleted...
How to keep added files as they are?
UPDATE: That happens only when my local repository has an unpushed commit with those "added" files. If the pending folder contains some files unique for this feature branch and they have been already pushed, then everything is fine - only the files that have been moved on develop are moved during the pull operation.

It sounds like the move from pending into 5.0.1 is happening on develop? When you say "But this "move" deletes also all files from the pending folder that you've added working on your local changes." Since the files were only moved on develop, then this problem should only happen if those files were already merged into develop. Files only on the feature branch should remain.
